# Unable to trigger the onchange event in datepicker and unable to use name attribute to set the value pciked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

````
```
const initialValues = {
    code: '',
    product: '',
    checked: 'false',
    jobCardNo: '',
    openDate: '',
    completionDate: '',
    serial: '',
    technicalNo: '',
    lineNo: '',
    show: false,
  };
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleInput = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any } }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```
````

I am using the above object for handling the input fields, when coming to the Material UI date picker unable to do it. The name attribute doesnt exist in date picker. Any solution for this.Thanks in Advance

````
```
<DatePicker
 value={props.openDate}
 onChange={props.handleInput}
 renderInput={(params) => (
 <TextField name="openDate" {...params} />
 )}
 />
```
````

Comment: yeah looks like the `name` exists on `TextField` not on `DatePicker` itself

Comment: yeah that works if i use name attribute in textfield. I want to use in DatePicker?